# How to apply different colormaps in different subplots?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

I'm doing more or less the following:

```
figure
for ii=1:4
    subplot(2,2,ii)
    imshow(image(ii))
    hcb = colorbar;

    switch ii
        case 1
            colormap(myMap)
            set(hcb,'YTickLabel', .. )
            set(hcb,'YTick', .. )
        case 2
            colormap(myMap)
            set(hcb,'YTickLabel', .. )
            set(hcb,'YTick', .. )
        case 3
            colormap(myMap)
            set(hcb,'YTickLabel', .. )
            set(hcb,'YTick', .. )
        case 4
            colormap(aDifferentMap)
            set(hcb,'YTickLabel', .. )
            set(hcb,'YTick', .. )
    end
end
```

What I'm facing is that calling `colormap(aDifferentMap)` for the fourth plot (`ii=4`), screws things up for the previous three plots: in my final figure all colorbars have `aDifferentMap` colormap, with also some problems to the `YTick` attribute.

If I comment out `colormap(aDifferentMap)` in case 4, it all works well (except for the fourth subplot, which will have a wrong colormap and no Ytickes whatsoever).

How can I deal with this? How can I set properties of `subplot(2,2,4)` without influencing subplots 1:3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **Matlab 2014a and before** applies the [**answer of Phil Goddard**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331299/2605073) and you need to use e.g. [**`freezeColors`**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors---unfreezecolors) from FileExchange.

---

In **Matlab 2014b** the problem got solved with the [**update of the graphics engine to version HG-2**](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-graphics/). Now the colormap *affects all axes in the figure, unless you set an axes colormap separately.* (from [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html))

```
figure
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
surf(peaks)
colormap(ax1,spring)

ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);
surf(peaks)
colormap(ax2,winter)
```

[image]

Comment: After a quick check in meta, I found this is the answer I should accept as it is more complete and probably more useful for future readers. However, being on R2011a, I found my solution through Phil Goddard's link. Namely I used both [freezeColors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors---unfreezecolors) and [cbfreeze](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24371-colormap-and-colorbar-utilities--jul-2014-) tools, as suggested by `freezeColors` author.

Comment: It would be absolutely fine to accept Phil's answer, as he solved your problem first. I just felt his answer his answer wasn't complete, especially because its recent changes in validity.

Answer (score 1):

Colormap is a property of the figure, not the axes, so changing it for a subplot changes it for all subplots.

Have a look at [Using multiple colormaps in a single figure](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/) for an example of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ind2rgb](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) if you just want to show **images** with different colormaps in a figure:

```
load flujet;
subplot(221); image(ind2rgb(X, gray(63)));
subplot(222); image(ind2rgb(X, jet(63)));
subplot(223); image(ind2rgb(X, hot(63)));
subplot(224); image(ind2rgb(X, copper(63)));
```

However, different colorbars still can't be shown in earlier versions of MATLAB.